Question related to continuity and differentibility of $f(x,y)$

Let $$ f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 
\dfrac{y \sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{x} & \text{if } x \ne 0, \\
0 & \text{if } x = 0. \end{cases} $$

Which of the following is/are true statement?

$f(x,y)  $ is continuous at $(0,0)$.


$f(x,y)$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Put $x=r\cos(\theta), y=r\sin(\theta)$ we get $f(r,\theta)=\tan(\theta)|r| \to 0$ as $r \to 0 $ $\lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)} f(x,y)=f(0,0)$. so $f(x,y) $ is continuous function. so (1) is true.
for differentiable,  $ f_x{(0,0)} = f_y{(0,0)} = 0 $
$\lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)} \frac{f(h,k)-f(0,0) - hfx_{(0,0)}-kfy_{(0,0)}}{\sqrt{(h^2+k^2)} } \to 0 \iff  $ $f(x,y)$ is differentiable.---(*)
after putting in (*) we get
$\lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)} \frac{k\cos (\theta)}{h \sin (\theta)}$ clearly it does not exists.
Hence $f(x,y)$ is not differentiable at origin. (2) is false.
Please can someone verify that the my above arguments are valid or not.
Thanks in advanced.

@AngaeMT It is just typo error..

Looks good to me!

You forgot to specify that you are investigating continuity and differentiability at zero only. You proof of continuity at zero is incomplete, it only holds for $\theta\neq \pi/2,-\pi/2$, so you do not have an entire neighbourhood of the origin. In fact, taking this into account, it is easy to check that your conclusion is false.

@LPZ Ohh yes! when $\theta= \pi/2 , -\pi/2$ then limit is indeterminate form so it is NOT always equals to zero. Hence $f(x,y)$ is not continuous at origin.
